# Angular & Spring Boot 2 & OAuth2 Client

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I have configured my spring boot as below:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myClient:
            client-name: name
            client-id: yyyyyy
            client-secret: xxxxx
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
        provider:
          myClient:
            issuer-uri: some-issuer-uri
```

This OAuth2 **code flow** - works fine (if I'd like to use only Spring not both Spring & Angular). When I request for any resource (for ex. `localhost:8080/api/user`), Spring moves me to the login page of my issuer, after that, I will be redirected to Spring. Spring creates a new session and that how he recognize me during future requests.

**How to deal with that in Angular?** How the flow should looks after the user click `login` button on the frontend?

Some facts:

1. Angular works on different port 4200. On production also it would be a separate microservice because it would work under `nginx`.
2. I would like to have this `OAuth2 code flow`. I don't want to replace it for ex. by the implicit flow.

(I would have 2 microservices, I don't want to move Angular `build` folder into `static` folder of tomcat)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Madalina nope :(